# mvc3 jquery on change load dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist on Page1 and when a user changes an element on that dropdownlist I would like to load another dropdownlist using Jquery it sounds simple in theory but it's not working for me.. here is what I have **Page 1** and I get an error on **@Url.Content('~/listings/service')** saying too many characters in character literal.

```
 // Load the new dropdownlist on change
  <script>
    $("#adtype").change(function () {
        $("#div1").load("@Url.Content('~/listings/page2') #service");
    });
</script>
// if a user changes this  dropdownlist it should trigger the jquery code
 <select name="adtype" id="adtype">
<option>Sales</option>
<option>Marketing</option>
 </select>

  <div id="div1"></div>
```

**page 2**

```
<select name="service" id="service">
<option>yes</option>
<option>no</option>
 </select>
```

Whats the best way to get this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is server-side C# code:

```
@Url.Content('~/listings/page2')
```

In C#, single-quotes are for character literals and double-quotes are for string literals.  (As opposed to JavaScript, in which both can be used for strings.)  Since that's a string and not a single character, it needs to be double-quotes:

```
@Url.Content("~/listings/page2")
```

---

As a side note, is `/listings/page2` really static content, or is it an action on the `Listings` controller?  If the latter then you'll want to change this to use `@Url.Action()` instead, so it's more portable:

```
@Url.Action("Page2", "Listings")
```

That's just a theory, though.  It might not be true based on your setup, just seems that way based on MVC standards and the fact that your "content" doesn't have a file extension.